# IIS: 502 when posting multipart/form-data and using ARR

Tags: iis, file-upload, multipartform-data, arr

We have a classic ASP.NET web api that is exposing a file upload endpoint. The file upload accepts a multipart/form-data request that holds the file. The format is:

```
POST https://dev.appname.com/api/v2/visitors/{{visitorId}}/attachments/upload
X-API-Key: {{apiKey}}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XXX

--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png

{{ file bytes }}
--XXX--
```

We use the following rewriting:

```xml
<rule name="Rewrite to dev REST API" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/(v[0-9]+/.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(dev|dev-testing).appname.com" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://restapidev.appname.com/api/{R:1}?tenant={C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

So the url is rewritten from: [https://dev.appname.com/api/v2/visitors/{{visitorId}}/attachments/upload](https://dev.appname.com/api/v2/visitors/%7B%7BvisitorId%7D%7D/attachments/upload) to [https://restapidev.appname.com/api/v2/visitors/{{visitorId}}/attachments/upload?tenant=dev](https://restapidev.appname.com/api/v2/visitors/%7B%7BvisitorId%7D%7D/attachments/upload?tenant=dev)

This gives us a response 502.

When hitting the https://restapidev.appname.com/api... url directly, the request is successful.

To diagnose the issue, I am writing the request body to a file:

```cs
    private async Task SaveRequestBody() {
      var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
      using var fileStream = File.OpenWrite($"C:\\temp\\{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-UploadAttachment.txt");
      await req.GetBufferedInputStream().CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
```

I notice that:

- When going through the dev.appname... url:

  - ❌ an empty file is written
- When going through the restapidev.appname... url

  - ✅ the full request, including the upload is written to a file
- When uploading a file without multipart/form-data (Content-Type: image/png, bytes directly posted in the request body)

  - ✅ the full request, including the upload is written to a file

Application logging seems to indicate that the application "hangs" on reading the request stream.

I have enabled failed request tracing, and noticed this:

- At **12:36:37.144**: GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START
- At **12:38:37.504**: GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END (2 minutes later!!)

  - BytesReceived="0", ErrorCode="The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)"

FYI: There's a warning `REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE` in the trace as well, but succesful requests have this warning as well.

I was not able to add the full log here (due to length restrictions on the post).

So our web application seems to "hang" while reading the request body:

- only for an multipart/form-data upload
- only when routed through ARR

Is there something that could be misconfigured?

Comment: This link should help you: [Troubleshooting 502 Errors in ARR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr).